# FormBuilderDateRangePicker doesn't work anymore

Tags: flutter, dart

My application supports the datepicker framework. This builder was working great until a few days ago. My code is like this:

```dart
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              FormBuilder(
                key: _fbKey,
                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                initialValue: {
                  'movie_rating': 5,
                },
                enabled: false,
                child: Column(
                   children: <Widget>[
                      FormBuilderDateTimePicker(
                         onChanged: (val) => onEditing(val),
                         autofocus: true,
                         locale: Locale(_myLocale),
                         name: "choose_date_range",
                         firstDate: DateTime(2017),
                         lastDate: DateTime( DateTime.now().year+1),
                         format: DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd"),
                         ...
```

I'm using [flutter_form_builder](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_form_builder) package.

This is the hierarchy of my code, FormBuilderDateTimePicker does not show a calendar anymore, any thoughts?

Comment: What is the parent of `FormBuilderDateRangePicker`, in my case it is working.

Comment: Can you edit the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue coming from `FormBuilder` `enabled: false,` . Comment or set   `enabled: true,`

```dart
     FormBuilder(
                // // key: _fbKey,
                autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.always,
                initialValue: {
                  'movie_rating': 5,
                },
                enabled: true, //<- here
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
```

> `enabled` => Whether the form is able to receive user input.
> When `false` all the form fields will be disabled - won't accept input -
> and their enabled state will be ignored.

Comment: Thank you! This field has changed name and for some reason it was working great before.